# Query to get all instead of FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, database

I need to iterate through all items in a subtree.
Therefore, I want to put all childItems of an predecessor into an array. I tried:

```
var successors = 
    TabWebContext.MenuItemSet.Where(m => m.PredecessorId == parentId).ToArray();
```

I also tried it without `.ToArray()` and with `.ToList()`.

I have the following loop: `while (successors.Count()>0){...}` (or rather `.Length>0`).

**The condition is never true.**
What do you think am I making wrong? I know there are elements (if I do `.FirstOrDefault()`, there is at least one element found.

Comment: What Error do you get?

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: Are you using linq2sql? EF? LLBLGen? NHibernate? Dapper? ADONet? You have not provided any useful info

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code as it is. What do you expect this code to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: What is current result are you getting and what is the  expected output..?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani no error, but I updatet my question with a condition never is true

Comment: EF @JoePhillips

Answer (score 1):

Why do you feel that it needs to be in an array to iterate through it? You could iterate the list like this:

```
foreach (var successor in TabWebContext.MenuItemSet.Where(m => m.PredecessorId == parentId))
{
   // do stuff with 'successor'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an example of how select all from data source works with `where` clause.

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 34, 23, 11 }; //data source >> can be EF or ADO.NET
var result = numbers.Where(n => n <= 20).ToList(); // select all with filteration
foreach(int  i in result ) //just to loop and
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

output :

```
22
11
```

so there is no issue can be seen in `var successors = 
    TabWebContext.MenuItemSet.Where(m => m.PredecessorId == parentId).ToArray();`

if you do facing an error then show that in your question.

Comment: Not an error but I added the loop with a condition never evaluates to true to my question. @KeyurRamoliya